# How to use Abstract Base Classes in Python?

Tags: python, abstract-class, abc

Following [this tutorial](http://pymotw.com/2/abc/) I'm trying to use Abstract Base Classes in Python. So I constructed two files:

**basis.py**:

```
import abc

class PluginBase(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def load(self, input):
        return
```

and **implementation.py**:

```
import abc
from basis import PluginBase

class SubclassImplementation(PluginBase):

    def load(self, input):
        print input
        return input

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'Subclass:', issubclass(SubclassImplementation, PluginBase)
    print 'Instance:', isinstance(SubclassImplementation(), PluginBase)
```

running `python implementation.py` works fine, but I now want to use `implementation.py` as a module for something else. So I get into the command line and do:

```
>>> from implementation import SubclassImplementation as imp
>>> imp.load('lala')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method load() must be called with SubclassImplementation instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
>>>
```

What am I doing wrong here, and how can I make this work? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need to *create an instance*:

```
from implementation import SubclassImplementation as imp

imp().load('lala')
```

This is not a specific ABC problem either; this applies to all Python classes and methods, unless you make `SubclassImplementation.load` a `classmethod`.

Comment: As I said to Daniel as well, I've been working way to much with php static functions lately (bLuh, I love Python!) that I totally forgot this. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't have anything to do with ABCs.

The object you've called `imp` is a class, ie SubclassImplementation. You'll need to instantiate it before you can call any of its instance methods. Alternatively, you could make `load` a classmethod.

Comment: How stupid of me. I have been working a lot with Static functions in php lately, so I got so used to directly running functions from a class, that I just forgot about instances. Thanks anyway!